# How to access collectionView from a different class in Swift

Tags: ios, class, swift, collectionview

I subclassed CollectionViewCell were I add different labels, animations and buttons.

I am trying to delete a cell and update the collectionView in one of my methods in this class(CollectionViewCell) but I'm unable to access collectionView from here since it was declared in another class/viewController.

**My CollectionView Class:**

```
//this is how I have declared the collectionView.
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
}
```

**My CollectionViewCell Class:**

```
//this is what I'm trying to achieve although I know it's incorrect.
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

func handlePanGesture(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

 FirstViewController.collectionView.reloadData()//

  }
```

Comment: It would be better to make the controller the target of the gesture recognizer. The cell class shouldn't know about the collection view, and shouldn't be responsible for deleting a cell -- that's the controller's job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @rdelmar says that's better do put the panGestureRecognizer into the controller.

Then you can access the indexPath with `collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(recognizer.locationInView(collectionView))`

Otherwise, you can use NSNotificationCenter with:

`NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification(name: "CellPanned", object: recognizer)`

and in the controller

`NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,selector:"cellPanned:" name: "CellPanned")`

and then implement:

```
func cellPanned(notification:NSNotification) {
    let gestureRecognizer = notification.object as! UIPanGestureRecognizer
    // Handle pan
}
```

Comment: hm, I can't put the gesture recognizer in the FirstViewController because the recognizer uses some NSLayoutConstrains declared and hooked up in this class. I'll try the second option and will post back.

Comment: Looks like it's working but how would I access the indexPath in func cellPanned(notification:NSNotification) { } ?

Comment: The same way as method 1 :

collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(recognizer.locationInView(collectionView))

Comment: there's no "recognizer" variable in fun cellPanned, I only have the "notification" variable in that method and I have a hard time trying to figure out how to get the location in view from a notification. The recognizer is still in the CollectionViewCell class because as I said earlier, I have to have it there because of other variables  and constrains I'm performing on the collectionViewCell....

Comment: When you post the notification with :

`NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification(name: "CellPanned", object: recognizer)` upon each call of didPan:, 

The recognizer would be notification.object

Comment: And still not matter how many excuses you have for architecturing it that way, all of those are not valid! :)

Comment: Thanks again for your time! I'm such a noob, didn't see I had the object set to nil...although I still disagree with putting the recognizer in the controller so I just ended up using collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(notification.object!.locationInView(collectionView))!

Comment: @Victor-------- I've been using iOS for the past 5 years, like you said, you're a noob. I was doing the same mistakes as you before. You should take the advices from experienced developers :)